# Entity Framework 7, Insert or Update

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estive procurando um método para verificar se um objeto existe na base, se existir, executar um `update`, se não existir, `insert`.

Não encontrei em nenhum lugar algo que me atendesse, então fiz o seguinte código:

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity) where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo pId = entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
    if (pId != null)
    {
        object valId = pId.GetValue(entity);
        if (dbSet.Any(p => p.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(p).ToString() == valId.ToString()))
        {
            T e = dbSet.Where(p => p.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(p).ToString() == valId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (PropertyInfo p in e.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite && x.Name != "Id"))
            {
                p.SetValue(e, p.GetValue(entity));
            }

            dbSet.Update(e);
        }
        else
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Como sempre leio algo sobre maneirar no uso de reflection, e procuro otimizar o código, a pergunta é simples:

**Há outra forma de fazer esse método, ou melhorar este código ?**

> A princípio, não tenho nenhum problema com ele, e funciona perfeitamente. Apenas uma questão de não fazer gambiarra e otimizar o código.

Estou utilizando ASP.NET Core, com Entity Framework Core e não tenho prática com esses.

***Edit:***

Consegui esse outro método (*parece melhor, mas ainda tem `reflection`*):

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this ApplicationDbContext context, T entity) where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo ps = entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
    if (ps != null)
    {
        DbSet<T> set = context.Set<T>();
        if (set.Any(x => ps.GetValue(x).ToString() == ps.GetValue(entity).ToString()))
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            set.Add(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma classe para criar um método de extensão com o nome `InsertOrUpdate<T>` genérico, nesse código se busca primeiramente a(s) chave(s) primária(s) de suas configurações que foram feitas para o seu `Model`, com isso é feita a busca em sua tabela para ver se os dados já foram persistidos e com essa informação toma a decisão se é `Add` ou `Update` que deve ser feito, ***exemplo***:

```cs
public static class Utils
{
    public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this DbContext context, T model)
        where T: class
    {
        EntityEntry<T> entry = context.Entry(model);            
        IKey primaryKey = entry.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey();            
        if (primaryKey != null)
        {
            object[] keys = primaryKey.Properties.Select(x => x.FieldInfo.GetValue(model))
                                            .ToArray();
            T result = context.Find<T>(keys);
            if (result == null)
            {
                context.Add(model);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Detached;
                context.Update(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Como utilizar:***

```cs
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    Cliente c = new Cliente();                
    c.Nome = "StackOverFlow";               

    db.InsertOrUpdate(c);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

***Nota:*** esse exemplo vai sempre gerar uma `SQL` para buscar informação (*se existe ou não*) e outra `SQL` que pode ser entre `INSERT` ou `UPDATE`, poderia até verificar mais simples onde o valor da propriedade fosse `0`, faria então um `INSERT` e maior do que `0` faria uma `UPDATE`, mas, isso só iria funcionar para `Model` simples com uma chave auto incremento, o método acima funciona inclusive para chave que possui mais de um campo e não são incrementado pelo banco e também vale lembrar que é o ideal é sempre configurar seus `Model` no modo `Fluent`, como ***exemplo*** logo abaixo:

`Model`:

```cs
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{        
    public int Chave1 { get; set; }        
    public int Chave2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

---

`Context`:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .ToTable("Clientes")
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .ToTable("Test")
            .HasKey(x => new { x.Chave1, x.Chave2 });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
           .Property(x => x.Chave1)
           .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .Property(x => x.Chave2)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .Property(x => x.Valor)
            .IsRequired();

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection_strings", options =>
        {
        });
    }
}
```

---

Se ainda quiser conferir se sua chave tem o valor `0` e nesse caso daria um `INSERT` e se o valor for maior do que `0` daria um `UPDATE` o método de extensão mudaria para esse:

```cs
public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this DbContext context, T model)
    where T : class
{
    EntityEntry<T> entry = context.Entry(model);
    IKey primaryKey = entry.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey();
    if (primaryKey != null)
    {
        object key = primaryKey.Properties.Select(x => x.FieldInfo.GetValue(model))
                                          .FirstOrDefault();                
        if (key.ToString() == "0")
        {
            context.Add(model);
        }
        else
        {                    
            context.Update(model);
        }
    }
}
```

só que esse código funcionaria como já falado somente para chave primária com um campo auto incremento.

***Observação:*** o grande problema do código que está na sua pergunta é que o valor da chave primária é fixo e isso obriga sempre ser a chave primaria da sua tabela com o nome de `Id`, no que está na resposta pode ser qualquer nome, só precisa mesmo estar configurado como foi explicado anteriormente.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [IKey Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ikey)
- [EntityType Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.entitytype)
- [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata)

Comment: Muito obrigado @Virgilio, por hoje já estou parando, mas amanhã implemento e dou o feedback. Boa noite!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Virgilio, muito obrigado!